# Mean function always returns NULL in R

Tags: r

The mean function is always returning NULL, no matter what I input. For example, `mean(1)` and `mean(c(1, 2, 3))` both return NULL. I tried this on another computer and it gave me the correct values. I am using RStudio Version 2022.02.2 Build 485, "Prairie Trillium" Release for macOS and have unchecked all packages except 'base' in my library. Thanks!

Comment: just run `rm(mean)` and try running `mean(c(1,2,3))` again

Comment: Aside - never name user-defined objects same as known methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have redefined the `mean` function and this new definition as been saved as part of the [workspace](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711843-Working-Directories-and-Workspaces-in-the-RStudio-IDE). This workspace is loaded again when you start `R` and overwrite the definition of `mean` from `base`.

With the limited information you have provided, here are a few pointers:

```
mean(seq(3))
# overwriting base mean so mean(seq(3)) returns NULL
mean <- function(...) NULL
mean(seq(3))
base::mean(seq(3))
# restoring mean to base::mean
mean <- base::mean
mean(seq(3))
```

returns:

```
2
NULL
2
2
```

If you redefine `mean <- base::mean`, this will likely solve your issue.